# Similar Code working in local but not in AWS box, undefined local variable error nil :NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, simple-form

Below is my part of code. This code is working fine in local machine, but i am having the same code running in AWS box and its showing error as

```
undefined local variable or method `elements' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #77):

74: <% if user_signed_in? %>
75:  <div class= "commentBox">
76:   <%= simple_form_for :dumb, url: ticker_comment_path(:id => @ticker.id, :by => (current_user.first_name + current_user.last_name)) do |f| %>
77:     <%= f.input :comments %>  
78:    <%= f.button :submit, "Add Comment", class: "btn addComment btn-success" %>
79:   <%end%>
80: </div>
```

Any idea/hint why ? i checked the database also and it has `comments` column as well.

I just checked again, by removing column `:comments` and replacing `:commented_by` from same table and its showing without error. I also checked in model for `attr_accessible :comments`

Comment: Can you provide the whole error message?

Comment: Resolved it. I replaced `:comments` param to another random param like `:usercomments` and it worked. I dont know why it worked but it worked. I guess `:comments` param was somehow conflicting with table `:comments` column. Not sure of the exact reason.